# Django migrations creating different tables name

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, mariadb

I have a SQL file which I am able to import into mariadb database. After importing I need to sync the data base ( makemigration ). While migrating if my class name is car then it is creating table as app-name_car, but I want the table name to be only car so I can sync the data in future.

Is there any way so that I can create the table name only as car. If not why this is so?

I am using xampp server for mariadb and django server to host the website.

Comment: Yes. its was so simple. Thanks!

Comment: ou are most welcome. Since you are still new here, may i point out that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the database table name, use the db_table parameter in class Meta. This is covered by the Django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.9/ref/models/options/#db-table).

Example:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    class Meta:
         db_table = 'car'
```

Comment: I was faster by 26 seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [db_table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#db-table) meta option

> **Options.db_table**
>   The name of the database table to use for the model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ....
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'car'
```